# Register spreadsheet to xml conversion

Tags: xml, system-verilog, verification, uvm

How can we convert the register spreadsheet to XML file for giving the XML file input to ralgen?

Answer (score 0):

Most spreadsheet programs offer XML as a "save as" file type option.